# Guardar um objeto dentro de um array sem sobrescrever o antigo javascript

Tags: javascript, array, objetos

Estou aprendendo javascript e já quebrei bastante a cabeça com isso,olhei vários fóruns e perguntas aqui no site mais não consegui resolver o problema.quero pegar o valor de dois inputs e criar um objeto com ele e depois guardar em um array,e depois digitar outros valores e fazer o mesmo,so que esta duplicando e não guardando cada objeto.
aqui e meu html:

```js
obj = {}
n1 = []

function pessoa() {
  obj.nome = document.getElementById('nome').value
  obj.idade = document.getElementById('idade').value

  n1.push(obj)
  console.log(n1)

  document.getElementById('res').innerHTML += `O nome digitado foi ${obj.nome} e a idade foi ${obj.idade}</br>`

  document.getElementById('nome').value = ""
  document.getElementById('idade').value = ""
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" id="nome">
  <input type="number" id="idade">
  <input type="button" value="enviar" onclick="pessoa()">
  <div id="res"></div>
</div>
```

no html esta armazenando,mais quando olho no console esta duplicado o array de objetos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso ocorre, pois você sempre trabalha na variável `obj`, com isso, você sempre reescreve os valores da variável e adiciona ela novamente no array, como todas as posições do array apontam para a mesma variável, você acaba tendo essas dados iguais.

---

Uma forma muito simples de corrigir isso, é declarar a variável `obj` dentro da função `pessoa`:

```
function pessoa() {
    let obj = {};
```

---

Com isso seu código final vai ficar mais ou menos da seguinte forma:

```js
let n1 = [];

function pessoa() {
    let obj = {};

    obj.nome = document.getElementById('nome').value;
    obj.idade = document.getElementById('idade').value;

    n1.push(obj);
    console.log(n1);

    document.getElementById('res').innerHTML += `O nome digitado foi ${obj.nome} e a idade foi ${obj.idade}</br>`;

    document.getElementById('nome').value = "";
    document.getElementById('idade').value = "";
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" id="nome">
    <input type="number"  id="idade">
    <input type="button" value="enviar" onclick="pessoa()">

    <div id="res"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: não sei como agradecer cara,muito obrigado mesmo,foi uma tarde inteira lendo muita coisa tentando evitar fazer perguntas bobas aqui.